# How to declare and init variable in a dbt model in `.sql` file with big query adaptor?

Tags: dbt

I would like to declare and init a variable in a dbt model `customer.sql` file.
I used the keyword `DECLARE` to declare a variable like the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) suggests but I got
a `Syntax error` on `DECLARE` keyword.

Code:

```sql
DECLARE myDate VARCHAR DEFAULT '2021-01-01';

with order_bis as (

    select
        order_id

    from
        order
    where
        customer_date > myDate

)

select * from order_bis
```

Error:
`Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got keyword DECLARE ...`

Answer (score 9):

It seems that using SQL variables does not work "yet" with dbt.
You can use Jinja variable if you want to use static values in multiple places, so that you can rely on Jinja logic.

```
{% set myVar = '2017-01-01' %}

...

where
        customer_date > {{myVar}}

...
```

Comment: This example is broken. `{% set myVar = '2017-01-01' %}
select {{ myVar }}` yields `2015`. The query may run, but it's not doing what you want

Comment: what would work in this case is `customer_date > "{{ myVar }}"`

Comment: Seems to be the case in 2024, using Jinja instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can set them [in the SQL header](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/sql_header#create-a-bigquery-temporary-udf), e.g. as follows. Note that you [*can't* safely use `ref()` or `source()` in the header](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/2793).

```sql
-- Supply a SQL header:
{% call set_sql_header(config) %}
DECLARE myDate VARCHAR DEFAULT '2021-01-01';
{% endcall %}

with order_bis as (

    select
        order_id

    from
        order
    where
        customer_date > myDate

)

select * from order_bis
```